# Class inheritance (from Array) and custom methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm up against something I don't quite understand.

Here's the class I've created, and the driver code I'm running to test my method:

```
class Dog < Array
  def breathing?
    self.length > 1
  end
end

the_dog = Dog.new(["Arf", "Woof"])

puts the_dog.breathing?
# true

the_dog.shift

puts the_dog.breathing?
# false
```

How come, when I call #shift on the_dog, the_dog stops breathing?

Comment: Because `the_dog.length` isn't greater than 1. Did you want to use`>=`? Also, inheriting from core classes might not go well (sadly), use instance variables.

Comment: Especially inheriting from Array is bad. I have yet to see a use case where it'd be warranted.

Comment: Also, what's up with this array dog?

Comment: I think it's disrespectful to name man's best friend, "the_dog".

Answer (score 1):

Shift method returns the first element of self and removes it (shifting all other elements down by one). Returns nil if the array is empty.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.shift
=> [2,3]
```

So, In your case the first argument of the array is removed. Once its removed, the condition `the_dog.breathing?` is returned false.